# Npm error no entry on new build, with only moment.js as additional module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, npm

I have a React application hosted by Nginx in a docker container, which I was trying to update when I got a strange error on `npm install`. I cannot seem to isolate the root of the problem.

My docker file is very straightforward;

```
FROM node:12.18.3-alpine3.9 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/frontend
COPY package.json /usr/src/frontend/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/frontend/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My dependencies are quite easy as well. I have installed and uninstalled some dependencies before this update. The only new dependency is 'moment'.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "dateformat": "^4.0.0",
    "django-react-csrftoken": "^1.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-agenda": "0.0.8",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-select": "^3.1.1",
    "react-toastify": "^6.1.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.7.1",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now the error I receive upon `docker build -t gcr.io/.../...:v1.0.0 .` is:

```
#12 64.86 npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
#12 71.17 npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
#12 79.23 npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
#12 88.02 npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
#12 90.10 npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
#12 90.28 npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
#12 95.27 npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
#12 95.74 npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
#12 95.80 npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
#12 95.85 npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
#12 95.85 npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
#12 97.46 npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: Please update to v 2.2.x
#12 98.61 npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
#12 101.1 npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
#12 101.5 npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
#12 103.2 npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
#12 103.7 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#12 103.7 npm ERR! syscall spawn git
#12 103.7 npm ERR! path git
#12 103.7 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
#12 103.7 npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
#12 103.7 npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/Revln9/drag-drop-touch-polyfill-ES5-compiled.git
#12 103.7 npm ERR! enoent
#12 103.7 npm ERR! enoent
#12 103.7 npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
#12 103.7 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
#12 103.7 npm ERR! enoent
#12 103.8
#12 103.8 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#12 103.8 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-16T17_08_18_962Z-debug.log
```

I'm also quite curious how to take care of the deprecation warnings, as I believe they're all by indirect dependencies.

---

edit:
I'm running on Windows. I also cannot seem to find the error log in C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\npm_cache_logs\

Comment: I suppose alpine image doesn't have git, so `RUN apk update && apk add git` before `RUN npm run build` might solve it.

Comment: Thanks. Makes a lot of sense in hindsight. Fixed it with adding git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Akihito Kirisaki.

The container didn't have git and therefore threw an error.
Simply adding
`RUN apk update && apk add git` solved the issue.